# $Z$ is Normal$(\sigma,1)$, find UMVUE of $P(Z\leq 0)$.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given i.i.d. samples $X_1,...,X_n$ from Normal$(\sigma,1)$, find the UMVUE of $g(\sigma)=P_\sigma(Z\leq 0)$.

I tried to use Lehman-Scheffe theorem. We now that $\sum_1^nX_i$ is sufficient and complete for $\sigma$, and we could take $T(X)=1_{\{X_1<0\}}$ as an unbiased estimator for $P(Z\leq 0)$. Then by this theorem, $S(X)=E[T(X)|\sum_1^nX_i]$ is the unique UMVUE for $g(\sigma)$. The point I got stuck is calculating the conditional expectation $E[1_{\{X_1<0\}}|\sum_1^nX_i]$.

Thanks in advance for any help/hint/suggestion.

Comment: If $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. normal with unit variance, then, conditionally on $S=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, one has $X_1=(S/n)+aU$ where $U$ is standard normal independent of $S$ and $a^2=(n-1)/n$, hence $$P(X_1\lt0\mid S)=P(U\lt-S/(an)\mid S)=\Phi(-S/\sqrt{n(n-1)}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me more about how did you write $X_1$ in terms of $S$ and $U$. Is it quite obvious? I could not get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For every normal family $(X_1,S)$, conditionally on $S$, $X_1=bS+aU$ as in my first comment, for some well chosen $(a,b)$. This basic property is one reason for the success of gaussian families in modelling tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am just first year master student, your approach  is to high for me. I did not know this kind of fact (even it is not in our text book)

Comment: Then maybe you are able to compute the joint distribution of $(X_1,S)$?

Comment: Thank you again. Yes I can. I can let $X_i=S_i-S_{i-1}$ for $i=1,..,n$ then using transformation I can find joint distribution of $(S_1,..,S_n)$ then integrate $S_2..S_{n-1}$ variables to get {S_1,S_n} (calculation will be to messy and long), but then you mean use density $f(x_1|s_n)=f(x_1,s_n)/f(s_n)$ and then $P(X_1<0|S_n)=\int_{-\infty}^0f(x_1|s_n)dx_1$? if this true than okay but there might be a shorter way

Comment: Remember that $(X_1,S_n)$ is jointly normal hence the mean vector and the covariance matrix are (easy to compute and) enough to do everything.

Comment: $X_1$ and $S_n$ are normal ok. yet they are dependent, if I put them in a vector, how  will it be a bivariate? just calculating the covariance matrix makes them bivariate? i did not get it, but again thank you very much you are really helpfull

Comment: "if I put them in a vector, how will it be a bivariate?" ??? Please explain what you mean by "bivariate", you might not be using the word in its usual meaning. Next, please explain how this would be related to what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry for unclear sentences. I meant will it be bivariate normal. You have said $(X_1,S_n)$ jointly normal, that is why I asked this. But I solved it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But jointly normal implies bivariate normal, obviously, hence I fail to see your point. // If you solved the question, you are invited to post here your solution and even, after a while and if other users consider that it is valid, to accept it.